# IOS tableview issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, scene

I'm having an issue where my app will freeze if when I press it to got the next scene which is a view controller with a tableview nested inside of it. the app will only freeze when I've declared how many rows the table will have. If anyone knows how to fix this problem its be greatly appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the app will freeze"? Does it crash? Do you have an error log? Or does it just block the UI?

Comment: Please try to be clear when you post an issue. What do you mean by "if when i press it"? Press what? besides you said the app freezes when you specify the number of rows, but you must specify the number of rows. Otherwise, the app should give you a run time error. So, I believe, you didn't want to mean that. Please specify what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set dataSource of your table view? You must call `tableView.dataSource = self` somewhere in your code (most probably in viewDidLoad method)

Comment: I don't think, that was the issue as cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection are defined under UITableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that in `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` you are creating *new* cell every time the method is called. That is not how table views (or collection views) work.

The idea behind these components is to reuse their cells so that your application shows better performance. What if you have 1000 cells? You will create 1000 `UITableViewCell` objects for each cell? This is where [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:) comes in handy.

So set an identifier for your cell in Interface Builder, for example "Cell" and get the cell like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

This is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you set the correct reuse identifier for your table view cell (either in storyboard, or code).

Storyboard:

[image]

Of if you want to do it in code, put this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

Important to know that you should **only use one** of the above. If you define your UI in Storyboards, I recommend the first approach.

Then when you create the cell in `tableView(_:, cellForRowAtIndexPath)`, instead of this:

```
var cell = UITableViewCell()
```

Use a cell from the reuse queue like so:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you are creating object for cell, make sure you use reuse identifier.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```